# UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext with WebForms and WebAPI in the same project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have a legacy app that uses WebForms that I need to extend. I incorporated WebAPI for my newer functionality . It all works great until I start using async await.

In WebAPI UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext = false will cause HttpContext to be null. Setting it to true fixes this issue.

In WebForms UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext = true will causes some pages to just never return. It's like IIS just never returns a response. Setting it to false fixes this.

Is there someway to have it true for WebAPI and false for WebForms?

Comment: did you tried and get any final solution for Webforms without deadlocking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have it set at that level. The ASP.NET runtime in its process (technically app-domain) must use exactly one implementation.

My recommendation is to investigate your WebForms code and determine why it is deadlocking with the new SyncCtx. The vast majority of code should work just fine, so there must be something unusual there.